# Regex to check password strength in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to make a regular expression that can check the strength of password. A password is considered to be strong if:

- It has minimum length of 8 characters
- It must contains minimum 2 Upper case and 2 Lower case letter
- It must contains minimum 2 digits
- It must contains minimum 2 special characters from `$,%,&,!,#`

This is what i have done:

```
# Strong Password Checker
import re

password_regex = re.compile(r'[(A-Z){2}(a-z){2}(0-9){2}($%&!#){2}]{8,}')
if password_regex.match('testpassword'):
    print("Your password is strong")
else:
    print("Your password is weak")
```

The password supplies to this code is not strong but, it doesn't detect it as weak password, Instead it identifies it as strong password.

Initially i am learning regular expression, so i want to keep everything simple and clear, if someone help it would be really appreciated.

Comment: `[(A-Z){2}(a-z){2}(0-9){2}($%&!#){2}]` is a character class that accepts any single symbol there. So, it accepts, `(`, and then `A-Z`, and `)`, and `{`, and `2`, and `}`, and so on.

Comment: Not every string problem is a regular expression problem, and this is a good example where some simple code (e.g. `len(password)`, judicious use of `isupper()` and `islower()` or `string.ascii_uppercase`, etc.) would be _much_ simpler and clearer.

Comment: @Sheri, partly because it has already been asked. Please remember to search before asking a new question.

Comment: @Chris yes you are saying right that it could be better to use `isupper()` or `islower()` but as i mention in my that i am learning regex so i have to made it using regex, BTW thanks for you response and motivation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use multiple lookahead conditions in your regex:

```
^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})(?=(?:\D*\d){2})(?=(?:[^$%&!#]*[$%&!#]){2}).{8,}$
```

Or making it easier to read using `x` mode:

```
^
(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2})
(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})
(?=(?:\D*\d){2})
(?=(?:[^$%&!#]*[$%&!#]){2})
.{8,}
$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nu01Ed/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2})`: Lookahead condition to make sure there are minimum 2 uppercase letters
- `(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})`: Lookahead condition to make sure there are minimum 2 lowercase letters
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){2})`: Lookahead condition to make sure there are minimum 2 digits
- `(?=(?:[^$%&!#]*[$%&!#]){2})`: Lookahead condition to make sure there are minimum 2 of the given special characters
- `.{8,}`: Make sure we have 8 or more of length
- `$`: End

Comment: Note that it might be easier to read if you do it in several steps, all commented : one regex to check digits, one to check max characters, etc, and fail if any regex fail

Comment: Once we breakup this longish regex into different components like this: https://regex101.com/r/nu01Ed/2 then it is easier to understand.